# Callback error (Output graph.figure is already in use.) in Dash app - Python

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have this dataframe which will be updated every several minutes:

```
   Sample Name  Result  Concentration  Mean Diameter
0            A     244            122              8
1            A     150              8              3
2            A     133             78             10
3            B     567             34             40
4            B     122            622              4
5            B     100            180             20
6            C      55             20             12
7            C      10             11             50
8            C      76            230             37
9            D     230             67              2
```

I have created a dash app which plots this data. I want the type of graph to be selected from the dropdown menu, therefore I have 2 input callbacks:

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(children=[
                     html.Div(children=[dcc.Dropdown(options=[
                                              {'label': 'Viability', 'value':'fig_viability'},
                                              {'label': 'Mean Diameter', 'value': 'fig_diameter'},
                                              {'label': 'Concentration', 'value': 'fig_concentration'}],
                                              id='graph-selector')]]),

                     html.Div(children=[
                                  dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
                                  dcc.Interval(
                                      id='interval-component',
                                      interval=15 * 1000,  # in milliseconds
                                      n_intervals=0)])])])   

@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
                  [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
    def update_figures(n):
        
    df = pd.read_excel(...)

    fig_viability = px.scatter(df,
                            x="Sample Name",
                            y="Result",
                            color="Sample Name").update_layout(
     {'title': 'Viability Plot (%)')

      fig_diameter = px.scatter(df,
                          x="Sample Name",
                          y="Mean Diameter (microns)",
                          color="Sample Name").update_layout(
     {'title': 'Mean diameter Plot (microns)')

      fig_concentration = px.scatter(df,
                               x="Sample Name",
                               y="Concentration",
                               color="Sample Name").update_layout(
      {'title': 'Concentration Plot')

    @app.callback(
        Output('graph', 'figure'),
        [Input(component_id='graph-selector', component_property='value')]
    )
    def select_graph(value):
        if value == 'fig_viability':
            return fig_viability
        elif value == 'fig_diameter':
            return fig_diameter
        else:
            return fig_concentration
```

The callbacks don't work though.. It throws me errors such as this one:

```
"In the callback for output(s): graph.figure Output 0 (graph.figure) is already in use. Any given output can only have one callback that sets it."
```

I tried using `dash.extensions_enrich` but didn't help. Please, help me debug it and make it work :(

Answer (score 1):

So the problem as the error suggests is that you have 2 callbacks that have the same output. This is not allowed in Dash, an output can be associated with only one callback.

Usually, when you have an output that is altered by more than 2 callbacks, you should try to combine the 2 callbacks into 1. Meaning, you have the 2 inputs as inputs to this new callback, and the output will be the common one that is causing the error. So something like this:

```py
@app.callback(
        [Output('graph', 'figure')],
        [
            Input('graph-selector', 'value'),
            Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
        ]
    )
    def new_update_graph(selected_graph_type, n):
```

Now, since these 2 inputs will trigger the callback and both essentially have 2 different functionalities, you need to detect which one was triggered out of the 2 using the [`dash.callback_context`](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#determining-which-input-has-fired-with-dash.callback_context). Then based on which was triggered, you do what you wish with either pathway. Here is an extension of the above example:

```py
@app.callback(
        [Output('graph', 'figure')],
        [
            Input('graph-selector', 'value'),
            Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
        ]
    )
    def new_update_graph(selected_graph_type, n):
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if not ctx.triggered:
        button_id = 'No clicks yet'
    else:
        button_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
        if button_id == "graph-selector":
            # code for graph-selector original function goes here
            .
            .
        else:
            # code for intereval-update original function goes here
            .
            .
```